# Yii2 Регистрация и заказа в одном окне

Tags: yii2, activerecord, регистрация, корзина, multiple

Здравствуйте! Пишу специфичную программу на Yii2, и нужно сделать регистрацию и оформление заказа на одной странице.

Товары не нужно набирать, как в обычном ИМ, их немного. Товары расположены в таблице(~15 шт). Человек просто задает количество, нажимает кнопку "Зарегистрироваться".

Думал писать отдельный контроллер Cart, и кидать товары в сессии, но не вариант. Товаров то мало. И товары просто набираются на одной странице.
Использую таблицы:

Products - информация о товаре(Id, название, цена, путь к картинке, статус( 0/1)
Users - данные о пользователе. Уже готово - проблем нет;
Orders - данные о заказе.
Order_Products - заказанные продукты. (Id, order_id, product_id, name, quantity, price)

---

Товаров 15 шт. Но в таблицу Order_Products попадают только товары с выбранным кол-вом > 1.

Думаю реализовать при помощи Табличного ввода. Model::loadMultiple()/Model::validateMultiple().

**Но я не знаю, как сделать 15 input полей для таблицы Orders_Products, где отбираются значения с кол-во>0, где product_id соответствует реальному продукту, которые сохранятся в таблицу Orders_Products**

Yii2 я еще не так глубоко изучил, а мозгов не хватает, как это реализовать. Перечитал русскоязычную документацию, но хочется сделать коротко и грамотно. Помогите пожалуйста!

Что примерно нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Код с регистрацией пользователя я опустил)
**Контроллер**

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        $order = new Orders();
        $products = Products::find()->indexBy('id')->where(['status' => 1])->all();
    $count_order_p = count(Yii::$app->request->post('order_products', []));
        $order_products = [new OrderProducts()];
        for($i = 1; $i < $count_order_p; $i++) {
            $order_products[] = new OrderProducts();        
        }
        if (Model::loadMultiple($order_products, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($order_products)) {
            foreach ($order_products as $order_product) {
                $order_product->save(false);
            }
        }
        if (Model::loadMultiple($products, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($products)) {
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product->save(false);
            }
        }

        return $this->render(
            'signup',
            [
                'model' => $model,
                'order' => $order,
                'order_products' =>$order_products,
                'products' =>$products
            ]
        );
    }
```

**Представление**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <?php if (\Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')):?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><?= \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success')?></div>
           <?php endif?>
           <?php if (\Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')):?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?= \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error')?></div>
           <?php endif?>
          <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
          /*** Поля для регистрации пользователя ***/
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Фото</th>
                <th>Название</th>
                <th>Кол-во</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                /*Просто заполняю продукцию из таблицы Products*/
                <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $form->field($product,"[]name"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($product,"[]price"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($product,"[]quantity"); ?></td> /*Вот это поле должно заполнять таблицу Order_Products , но не знаю как*/
                        <td><?= $form->field($product,"[]image"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($product,"[]status"); ?></td>      
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        /*Здесь попробовал вывести таблицу Order_Products*/, выводит 1 строчку(
        </table>
          </br>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Фото</th>
                <th>Название</th>
                <th>Кол-во</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($order_products as $order_product): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $form->field($order_product,"[]product_id"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($order_product,"[]product_name"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($order_product,"[]order_id"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($order_product,"[]quantity"); ?></td>
                        <td><?= $form->field($order_product,"[]price"); ?></td>         
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
      </div>
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: получается у вас 1 пользователь может сделать 1 заказ, потому что он не сможет заказать без регистрации, а его уже не пропустит валидация, т.к существует уже такой пользователь, так?

Comment: Проблема не в регистрации. Там все впорядке. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как 15 полей с количеством забить в таблицу Order_Products. Т.е выбранные товары. По сути нужно 15 одинаковых Input. Но каждое поле привязано к отдельному продукту, а их еще и провалидировать нужно

Answer (score 0):

Для массового вывода можете использовать `GridView` и помещать в него `dataProvider`. Либо создавайте форму. Из контроллера передавайте Model с нужным `Products::find()->...`

А в View ловите так:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'product_id')->textInput()->label('id товара') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'product_name')->textInput()->label('Имя товара') ?>
<? /* таких 15 штук */ ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

`form->field` заполняет значения из БД и также берет (при отправке формы) с `textInput` и валидирует основываясь на ваших "rule" в модели `Products`.

Затем в контроллере ловите POST:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
{
    // какие-то действия и дополнительные проверки
    if($model->save()) { надпись об успешной записи и редирект на список }
}
```

Comment: Все верно, из таблицы Products я вытаскиваю Имя, цену и т.д. но количество я вытащить не могу. Количество должно записываться в таблицу Order_Products. И я не знаю, как его вытащить, чтобы каждое поле Кол-во соответствовало конкретному товару.
Записываю ведь я не в Products.